# Visual studio package manager not installing the files to project

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2022

Using Visual studio 2022 with new project for .net 6 MVC if try to install any nuget package (via nuget package manger on project) the actual css files etc for the package are not installed but the nuget package manager shows that it is installed. Example if I install date picker it shows the package is installed but there is no files for it 
[image: Image showing package installed but no files]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59496671/17296043) can help you to add the css file after installing the nuget package?

Comment: Defeats purpose of using package manager. Would have to manually install and check package versions if there are new versions for each package, whereas package manage would indicate which is outdated, etc.

Comment: NuGet has been revised significantly several times to remove legacy functionalities, so expecting a legacy package (dating back to 2015) is unrealistic. The JS ecosystem has moved fast on frameworks like React and tools like NPM, so staying with jQuery means that you won't get the best support either, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/the-new-javascript-typescript-experience-in-vs-2022-preview-3/